# Water getting into cottage

Tags: water, leak, waterproofing

I have been dealing with this problem ever since I purchased the property (Aug 2018). There is water that is getting into our backyard cottage -- no idea from where! It has created a musty smell, the baseboards are black, and woodbugs / worms are getting in too.

Things I have tried:

(1) used a concrete sealer (KRYTON) are the perimeter. This was my first guess, as the water seems to be localized to the baseboards.

(2) installed a french drain around the perimeter of the cottage, as the yard had standing water so I thought maybe water was seeping in somehow.

(3) Stripped sections of drywall to see how far the moisture goes.

Here are some photos:

Bathroom (the wood is dry, it was mostly wet on the concrete that can be seen, and between the vap barrier and drywall -- the drywall was very brittle):
[image]
[image]

Outside bathroom: 
[image]
[image]

Kitchen (underneath the baseboard):
[image]

Bedroom corner (1):
[image]

Outside corner of bedroom (1) (it's only wet because I sprayed the hose on there to see if water was coming in -- it wasn't):
[image]

Bedroom corner (2) (bone dry in the place where the insulation was):
[image]

Outside corner of bedroom (2) (it's only wet because I sprayed the hose on there to see if water was coming in -- it wasn't):
[image]

EDIT: I just removed some of the flooring to find that the black stuff between the flooring and the slab is very moist, and lots of wood bugs along the perimeter. Could it be ground water getting through the slab, collecting on the black stuff, and then flowing into the corners and sides of the cottage?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: To rule out moisture through the slab, duct tape a 6 inch square piece of plastic to the floor and wait 24 hrs to see if any moisture is coming through. Make sure to tape all 4 sides.  Aside from that in your 7th photo shows that the studs are near grade on the outside. Is that acceptable for the building code in your area?

Comment: Could it be condensation in the walls or eaves or from a roof leak? Roof leaks are difficult to find because water will flow along a beam or other surface for some distance before becoming apparent lower down.